Getting the list of Purchase Orderss on Acumatica
I am trying for the first time to get the Acumatica Purchase order list by apparently I need the version for the API? and I dont have access at all to the Acumatica ERP and I dont know what would be the actual endpoint for this request
So do you have some idea in previous projects you have worked with this how to make this request?
https://help.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=0ea8ce7c-4423-4286-a481-37e7261cc30f

{{baseUrl}}/PurchaseOrder

You can return only the fields relevant to your requirements with the $select parameter:
{{baseUrl}}/PurchaseOrder?$select=Type,OrderNbr,Date

